# Assign Permission Set on Package Installation

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, package-install

Can we just `add permission set to a user during the installation of the package`, I Mean if the user is system admin then assign Admin Permission set and for remaining Users assign user permission Set. During the Installation Process

> Is it possible to add?

If No what're the alternative solutions. Permission Set needed to be assigned for the usage of Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class which implements InstallHandler interface and write your logic in onInstall method this method will be invoked after package installation.

```
global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
  global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        //Your logic to add permission sets.
    }
  }
```

For more information you can refer salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm)